# How can I make a variable count how many times a while loop has run?

Tags: java

I'm required to code a program that, using a do-while loop, will print 25 prime numbers on a new line. I have everything figured out on it, except for printing out exactly 25 numbers. However, the program is only giving me prime numbers *up to* the number 25, not 25 prime numbers.

I set a variable "count" to increase every time the loop is run, with the same result. Here's my code (sorry for the length, I would shorten it but I'm worried the whole thing might be messed up):

```
        int firstNum;
        int secondNum = 1;
        int num;
        int count = 0;

    System.out.println("Sample run: \n\nPrime numbers");
        do {
            num = 0;
            firstNum = 2;
            while (firstNum <= secondNum / 2) {
                if (secondNum % firstNum == 0) {
                    num++;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
                firstNum++;
            }
            if (num == 0 && secondNum != 1) {
                count++;
                System.out.print("\n" + secondNum + " ");
            }
            secondNum++;
        } while(count < 25);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use for-loops instead of while-loops; 2) Declare the variables only where they are needed, not in the beginning. You program will be by orders of magnitude easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `count++;` inside first `if` block to get 25 prime numbers.

**Updated Code:**

```
    int firstNum;
    int secondNum = 1;
    int num;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("Sample run: \n\nPrime numbers");
    do {
        num = 0;
        firstNum = 2;
        while (firstNum <= secondNum / 2) {
            if (secondNum % firstNum == 0) {
                num++;
                // count++; // <--- Remove this.
                break;
            }
            firstNum++;
        }
        if (num == 0 && secondNum != 1) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(secondNum); // Use println() for new line.
        }
        secondNum++;
    } while(count < 25);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example showing how you can iterate through some loop a fixed number of times, and separately calculate your next prime number. I'm clearly not calculating any primes here, just showing how you can separate the two concerns of "loop quantity" and "determine the next prime".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int prime = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k <= 25; k++) {
        prime = findPrimeAfter(prime);
        System.out.println("#" + k + ": " + prime);
    }
}

private static int findPrimeAfter(int lastPrime) {
    // TODO: find the next prime that is greater than "lastPrime"
    return 0;
}
```